# Is the first dual equal to the third dual of a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, dual-spaces

let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$ and let $V'$ denote the dual of $V$, that is, the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $F$ equipped with the scalar product $(c\cdot f)(v) = c\cdot(f(v))$ and vector sum $(f+g)(v) = f(v)+g(v)$.

Is it always the case that $V'$ is isomorphic to $V'''$? Moreover, is it always the case that the natural homomorphism is an isomorphism between $V'$ and $V'''$? That is, the natural homomorphism being the map $\phi$ defined by $\phi(f)=g_f$ where $g_f$ is defined by $g_f(x) = x(f)$ and where $x$ is in $V''$ and f is in $V'$.

If this is not the case I would like a proof, otherwise I'd like a counter example. Thanks

Comment: You mean to ask if the *natural homomorphism* is an *isomorphism*.

Comment: @k.stm, yes, thank you for pointing that out, I'll fix it now

Comment: Are you assuming that $V$ is finite dimensional? Otherwise there's no chance to get an isomorphism between $V'$ and $V^{'''}$: Recall that an infinite-dimensional vector space is never isomorphic to its double dual. Hence, if $V$ is infinite dimensional so is $V'$ and therefore $V'$ can't be isomorphic to $V^{'''}$.